# AWS ubuntu 16.04 keeps forgetting ssh git key

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I have a server running on aws ec2 and i tried adding an ssh key

I`ve connected via ssh and ran:

`eval "$(ssh-agent)"`
`ssh-add key`

and it works for the current session, but when i close the connection and then open it again i have to repeat the process all over again...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make `ssh-agent` start when you create a session and tell your `~/.ssh/config` to add keys automatically to your agent [as described in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1152861):

> Add `[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
> to your ~/.bashrc or other startup script (~/.zshrc).
>
> The keys can be automatically added upon the first usage, when you add `AddKeysToAgent yes` to your ~/.ssh/config.